# Htaccess. Redirect from non-friendly Url

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I need friendly URL only for some pages on my website, I added this code to htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule languages/english-online.html languages/english.php
```

And now when I open in browser http://mydomain.com/languages/english-online.html I see the content of page "languages/english.php". It's OK

But I also want to do: if somebody tries to enter to http://mydomain.com/languages/english.php, he will be redirected to http://mydomain.com/languages/english-online.html

I've tried everything, I get or 500 error or nothing happends.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Redirect /languages/english.php http://mydomain.com/languages/english-online.html
```

Similar code worked for files on my own website.

Comment: What other rules have you added to .htaccess? Can you post the full contents of the file?

Comment: >AddDefaultCharset utf-8
>php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
>php_value session.cookie_lifetime 10800
>ExpiresActive On
>ExpiresDefault "access plus 4 hours"
>ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
>ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
>ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
>RewriteEngine On
>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
>RewriteRule languages/english-online.html languages/english.php
>Redirect 301 languages/english.php languages/english-online.html

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to add linenbreaks